# ASP.net MVC 3.0 General Validation Method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm just learning MVC 3.0 and `ValidationMessageFor` works great, but each one of those is attached to a specific user input.

How would I go about creating a general validation error?

I.E.: A number of fields are supposed to add up to 100. Each one individually has a possible range of 0-100, but combined should also not cross 100.

I want to notify the user of this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can always insert a record manually like so:

```
 if(numbers > 100)
   ModelState.AddModelError("key", "Message I want to show");
```

When you use

```
Html.ValidationSummary()
```

It will show up.

Comment: Thanks Tejs, what is the "key" isn't that linked to an attribute of the model? I tried calling "random" but the error wouldn't display. Thanks!

Comment: It's a dictionary under the hood. The 'key' is normally the property name.

Comment: Thanks Tejs for the help, but it doesn't seem to be working. Even when ValidationSummary is true it my separate message still doesn't show.

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this in the Model itself?

Comment: You can also use 
`Html.ValidationMessage("key")` 
to display an inline message wherever you want on the page, if you used the 
`ModelState.AddModelError("key", "Message I want to show");` 
functoinality.